# Application level willInsertElement event callback without views

Tags: ember.js

The purpose is to remove placeholder content when an application loads, so ideally it should only fire once on application load. In the olden days, the application view `willInsertElement` was sufficient for this purpose, but since views are passé, what's the accepted way to do this without them?

I thought about using `willTransition` on the application route, but that'll fire on every transition, not just the first time the application is instantiated.

### Tried

Using `willTransition` with a property that is set after it is first called, but `willTransition` is not called on first boot.

Using `didTransition` in the same fashion, but this leaves a significant flash of both placeholder content together with real content.

```
didTransition: function() {
  if (!this.getWithDefault('didInitialTransition', false)) {
    this.set('didInitialTransition', true);
    Ember.$('#initial-content').remove();
  }
}
```

Using `loading` event on the application route to queue a runloop function, but even `afterRender` occurs too soon.

```
loading: function() {
  if (!this.getWithDefault('didInitialTransition', false)) {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', () => {
      this.set('didInitialTransition', true);
      Ember.$('#initial-content').remove();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend accessing the dom from routes, you should instead set a property on the route's controller that toggles it

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but setting a property and reacting to that in the controller still leaves us with the same issues. I'm just cutting out the middle-man with these examples.

Comment: What you can do is stick a component in application.hbs and put the logic there.

Comment: @locks Yeah, that seems like the only way to reproduce the timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by catching the same hook in a thin component, and passing that back up to the controller as an action. This allows for the same render hooks to be used just about anywhere.

#### components/life-cycle.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  willInsertElement() {
    this.sendAction('beforeInsertElement');
  }
});
```

#### templates/application.hbs

```
{{life-cycle beforeInsertElement="beforeInsertElement"}}
```

#### controllers/application.js

```
...
  actions: {
    beforeInsertElement: function() {
      if (!this.getWithDefault('didInitialTransition', false)) {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('render', () => {
          this.set('didInitialTransition', true);
          Ember.$('#initial-content').remove();
        });
      }
    }
  }
...
```

This is probably only really useful in this limited circumstance, where there was otherwise no way to run code just before everything else was rendered on app first boot. Otherwise, you can just use the same Ember run loop code inside the route's `didTransition`, for example.